# Python: A character that appears to be a space but isn't a space. What is it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, char, space

This is in Python 3.4.

I'm writing my first program for myself and I'm stuck at a certain part. I'm trying to rename all of my audio files according to its metadata in python. However, when I try to rename the files, it doesn't finish renaming it sometimes. I think it is due to an invalid character. The problem is that I don't know what character it is. To me, it looks like a space but it isn't.

My code is here:

```
from tinytag import TinyTag
import os

print("Type in the file directory of the songs you would like to rename and organize:")
directory = input()
os.chdir(directory)
file_list = os.listdir(directory)

for item in file_list:
    tag = TinyTag.get(item)
    title = str(tag.title)
    artist = str(tag.artist)
    if artist[-1] == "\t" or artist[-1] == " ":
        print("Found it!")
    new_title = artist + "-" + title + ".mp3"
    #os.rename(item, new_title)
    print(new_title)
```

This is the list that it outputs: 
http://imgur.com/tfgBdMZ

It is supposed to output "Artist-Title.mp3" but sometimes it outputs "Artist -Title .mp3". When the space is there, python stops renaming it at that point. The first entry that does so is Arethra Franklin. It simply names the file Arethra Franklin rather than Arethra Franklin-Dr.Feelgood.mp3

Why does it do this? My main question is what is that space? I tried setting up a == boolean to see if it is a space (" ") but it isn't.

It ends the renaming by stopping once it hits that "space". It doesn't when it hits a normal space however.

Comment: That is a png, can't copy/paste to check. Post the original title as is. It may be an escape; in Arethra Franklin is no unicode char above 128, so if you try to read as ascii - bytes - you may see the char/sequence at that point.

Comment: After you have the artist string, try `print (ord(artist[-1]))` to see exactly what the character is

Comment: or `print(repr(artist))`

Comment: Okay I have done ord(artist[-1]] and it comes out as 0. That is null right? So I can simply check if the last char is equal to 0 and remove it if it does?

print(repr(artist)) has that character coming out as \x00

Comment: @DavidLe even better, just do `new_title = artist.strip("\x00") + "-" + title + ".mp3"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This question has been solved but if the answer is in the comments, how do I go about marking the question as solved? Should I or someone else answer post an answer then mark that as solved?

Comment: @DavidLe Hooked's answer is better. There could be more invalid characters than just `'\x00'` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the filename has some unicode in it. If all you are looking for is a file renamer, you could use [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) and handle the errors by replacing them with a `?` character. As an example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
funky_name = u"best_song_ever_пустынных.mp3"
print (funky_name)
print (funky_name.encode('ascii','replace'))
```

This gives:

```
best_song_ever_пустынных.mp3
best_song_ever_?????????.mp3
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) to find out what the "offending space" really is.

Comment: So would os.rename(name.encode, new_title) work? Wouldn't os.rename not recognize the new name.encode to find the file to rename? I mean the file is named name not name.encode right?

Comment: To clarify, I don't actually mean name.encode. I mean name.encode('encoding', 'replacement)