# Reading data from memory and decoding

Tags: memory, encoding, byte

I am trying to pattern match for string values residing in a process's memory. I have memory locations stored within a list, and then I iterate over the list and determine its contents.

```
for address in l:  
    print "\n\n"
    print address

    addressContent = str(address.read(100)).replace(" ", "")
    print addressContent[0:10] + "\n" + addressContent + "\n"
    print "s a v e d" == addressContent[0:10].lower()
```

I have no problem searching for my desired content (the string 'savedvariables') however the trouble comes with trying to determine the context around what I have searched for. Here is one result of this search.

```
<Addr: 0x00E2AF48 : "S\x00a\x00v\x00e\x00d\x00V\x00a\x00r\x00i\x00a\x00b\x00l\x00e\x00s\x00\\\x00C\x00a\x00r\x00t\x00o\x00g\x00r\x00a\x00p\x00\xa1"" (bytes)>
S a v e d
S a v e d V a r i a b l e s \ C a r t o g r a p í"╘╓r* ÇM i n i n g . l u a . b a k             ╗".╓

False
```

Why is it that I can't accurately determine the contents of memory after its been searched?

Comment: Note: Probably you are on windows or using a language which uses UTF-16 (or UCS-2). So when comparing strings (and not bytes), you may have additional (Unicode) problems (like not normalized strings).  If you are using python, you may have additional problems: encoding changes (sometime ASCII, sometime UTF-16 and sometime UTF-32, a PEP describe the internal encoding method).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I was looking at the Python docs, and unicode has its own type as compared to string ( https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type ). `str(address.read(100))` typecasted to a string appropriately (I tested this) which only confused me further. `print type(addressContent)` does return `<type 'str'>` as expected.

Comment: Just to make EXTRA sure, `print("'%s'"%addressContent[0:9].decode("ascii"))` output `'S a v e d'`. Furthermore, `print("s a v e d" == addressContent[0:9].lower().decode("ascii"))` output `False`.

Comment: IF you are just looking, you may want to go to python3. We know a lot better python3 (and Unicode handling is less confusing, but as I said, internally Python could save in different "encodings"). Python2 is at end of support. I assume there is something about byte `\x00` and how it is displayed. Note `\x00` is ASCII and the `\u0000` is also Unicode, but most programs do no handle it well (C,standard libraries and other languages use it as end of string). Python allows it.

Comment: Yeah you're completely right on that byte. Trying to remove it now.

Comment: OK just needed to decode in the right charset, `utf-16` :(

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing "s a v e d" to "s a v e d ", there's an extra char in the slice

```
string = 'S a v e d V a r i a b l e s \ C a r t o g r a p í"╘╓r* ÇM i n i n g . l u a . b a k' 
print(string[:10].lower())
```

s a v e d

```
print(string[:9].lower())
```

s a v e d

Edit: I was thinking about why your addressContent string has spaces after you replaced them, which leads me to think that they aren't actually spaces. Try using str.encode like in this link [Python: A character that appears to be a space but isn't a space. What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335448/python-a-character-that-appears-to-be-a-space-but-isnt-a-space-what-is-it)

```
addressContent = str(address.read(100)).encode('ascii','replace').replace("?", "")
```

This will hopefully remove the spaces.

Comment: `addressContent = str(address.read(100)).replace(" ", "")

print addressContent[0:9] + "\n" + addressContent + "\n"

print "s a v e d" == addressContent[0:9].lower()

print "s a v e d" in addressContent.lower()`

`False

False`

Comment: Just encoded to the wrong charset, needed `utf-16` but we were on the right track!